# In the enclosed context, can a linear mixed effects model be used in place of a general linear model when repeated measures are present?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I work within a field that has some fairly challenging datasets. Without going into too much detail, the following sequence of analyses are canonically performed:

1. Individual subjects have time series datasets. These datasets are modeled as being explained by some other predictor variable's values across time (i.e. I'm using one time series to predict another time series). This is canonically formulated in a GLM context. After running the GLM, a $\beta$ coefficient associated with the predictor time series will be output for the given subject.
2. Step 1 is repeated across all subjects so that each subject's GLM analysis has a corresponding subject-specific $\beta$ value.
3. All $\beta$ values (from all subjects) are now pooled together and treated as a collection of observations. Suppose from the beginning, all subjects were partitioned by one between-group categorical factor with two levels: treated vs control. A 2nd GLM is performed with a binary index ( $0$ for control and $1$ for treated) and a corresponding coefficient (to be solved for) $\gamma$.
4. After performing this 2nd GLM, a t-test can be conducted on $\gamma$ to determine if there is a difference between the beta values from the treated individuals versus the non-treated (control) individuals.

You can  imagine a scenario  where the original subject partitioning involves $n$ between-group factors. For simplicity, let us assume that $n=2$ and suppose that each factor has only two levels each. In this scenario, for the 2nd-level GLM, **is it correct to say** that my linear model is being implemented (conceptually) as follows:

> $\beta_i=\alpha_0+\gamma_1X_i+\gamma_2 Y_i +\varepsilon_i$

where $(X_i,Y_i)$ corresponds to $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, or $(1,1)$ depending on the particular factors that subject $i$ is described by.

**Secondly**, it is my understanding that the standard GLM does not permit within-group factors. Assuming this is true, I wondered if someone could clarify whether the following would be appropriate:

Still keeping $n=2$, suppose that now I have one between-group factor and one within-group factor. In this context, obviously we will have $\beta_i$'s that are potentially correlated with one another due to the repeated measures. Rather than employing the aforementioned 2nd-level GLM, I wondered if it would be appropriate to model my $\beta$  values using a linear mixed-effects model.

Comment: If you really have time series (that is, fairly long series, with dozens of time points) then I think you should be using time series methods. I am no expert on these, but I believe that, if you want to use one time series to predict another, then VARIMAX is a typical method.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have relatively small numbers of repeats, then I would like more detail of your step 1 above.  What exactly is done in the GLM that you mention?

Comment: @PeterFlom thank you for the engagement. The following reference https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-23/issue-4/The-Statistical-Analysis-of-fMRI-Data/10.1214/09-STS282.full …pages 13-16 should provide a more detailed summarization of the procedure I outlined above

Comment: @PeterFlom and, regarding your query about number of data points comprising the time series, there are somewhere between 10^2 and 10^3 time points

Comment: OK, then, I would use time series methods.

Comment: @PeterFlom thank you for the input, but I would note that the described approach is standard cannon within this field (which has thousands of publications each year…millions of dollars spent…etc) and your suggestion amounts to scrapping the methodology altogether. Is that correct?

Comment: As I said to start, I am no expert on this.